# Securing a subnet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, security

I have a primary (Actiontec used for wired) and a secondary (Linksys wireless) router.

I want the Linksys wireless router to be as isolated as I can from my Actiontec LAN connections.

Currently I have the Linksys router set as a WAP and on a different subnet.

I can connect to it fine and connect to the internet. I'm just wondering..How secure is this? I basically want anyone connecting from the wireless to be limited to just connecting to the internet, not connecting and seeing any other computers on the network.

**More Info:**
Actiontec MI424WR Router (Fios)
Linksys WRT54GL running DD-WRT

Currently Actiontec LAN running to Linksys WAN 
Linksys static IP set to 192.168.5.1 instead of 192.168.1.1 putting it on different subnet.

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is a static route set up to route traffic between your subnets, they are completely isolated.  They are logically, two different networks.  Traffic between them requires explicit configuration.

Have you tried to access your 192.168.1.x network while connected to the 5.x network?  Try pinging a host.  It should fail.

Comment: Not sure if I didn't subnet it correctly but I've tried and I can indeed PING and access the primary router still.